# validation loss and accuracy rising

Tags: keras, deep-learning, loss

I am using an MLP for classification

Here is my model

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])),
    keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(0.00015, decay_steps=1000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True)
optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I noticed that the [traning/validation loss and accuracy(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUXrq.png) validation loss increases as the validation accuracy increases.

Isn't loss supposed to decrease as accuracy increases?

Comment: Could you include the comparison of the loss and accuracy for training vs validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checkout out this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282160/how-is-it-possible-that-validation-loss-is-increasing-while-validation-accuracy). Another aspect that is not mentioned there, but I think is worth noting, is the class-balance in your data set. Since you are using Softmax as your final layer, eg multi-class classification, the reason you observe validation loss increases **and** validation accuracy increases could be because your data is imbalanced in regards to how many observations of each label(class) exist. Your classifier becomes better (more accurate) at determining your most frequent classes, but worse (less accurate) with the more rare classes. You could say that you are "overfitting" your model to more often predict the common classes.

Because of this, accuracy increases since your classifier is overall correct more often, but the loss increases as well, since the loss for the rare classes become large (since it predicts the probability of them to be 0).

To solve this, you could either upsample or downsample your data, or set class-weights as described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras).